# How to change minlength conditionally with jQuery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin.

I want to select the minlength dynamically.

Currently I am trying something like this, but it's not working.

```
minlength:function () {
    if(val == 1 ) {
        return 3;
    }
    else{
         return 1;
    }
},
```

I want to set `minlength` 1 or 3 according to a condition. How can i do this?

Comment: Do you want to set it at page load only?

Comment: Which jQuery validation plug-in is it? There are quite a few!

Comment: i want to set this every validation plugin call

Comment: i am using http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `val` is available in the scope, you have to execute the function to actually set the value, try this...

```
minlength:(function () {
    if(val == 1 ) {
        return 3;
    }
    else{
         return 1;
    }
})(),
```

Updated after Kanishka Panamaldeniya's clarification:

You have to add your own custom validator method, using addMethod(). See [here for further reference and examples](http://www.randallmorey.com/blog/2008/mar/16/extending-jquery-form-validation-plugin/).

Comment: i want to change this every validation call . i tried this but not working .

Comment: What validator plugin are you using? The link you posted refers to an autocomplete plugin, not to a validator one.